# Invalid UTF-8 as username?

Tags: panel, username

In my top panel, my username shows up as "[Invalid UTF-8]". Yet, on the login screen, it is correct. I had this problem once before and I was able to fix it, but I can't remember where I found how to do it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! The problem was that the System Settings application went missing. Reinstalling that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed the "accountsservice" package (via Synaptic Package Manager) and the problem went away. [Ubuntu Studio 12-04 64-bit]